# Django and S3 - static URL won't change

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I managed to set my S3 as a subdomain `static.domain.com` (using `CNAME` and bucket name the same as subdomain).Now I'd like to amend my django settings to use this URL.
I use `django-storages` and can't make it work.

I set `STATIC_URL` to `http://static.domain.com`.
When I use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in my templates - it works. But when I use `{% static %}` templatetag, or check my static files in the admin panel I see they use: `http://static.comain.com.s3.amazonaws.com`

I have no idea how to set it properly to make it work. I'd like to make my static (admin + www) to point to the correct URL which is `static.domain.com`

It's the same situation with media files.

Any clues? Am I missing some settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. All I had to do was to set this in my settings:

```
import boto.s3.connection

AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = boto.s3.connection.VHostCallingFormat()
```